# Spyder 3.0 won't let me run file

Tags: python, menu, spyder

Spyder 3.0, Windows 10 64-bit

Hello everyone, I used to be able to write code and run the files in Spyder without a problem but now the button to run the code is greyed out and I can't run the file. Not even using F5 or clicking Run from the Run menu tab.

[View my Spyder menu tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIPMN.png)

Additionally, Spyder used to color my text in different ways but now it's all black. I don't know what happened, I didn't change any settings. Doing some research I found out this can be edited by accessing the Preferences tab (Code Introspection) but that option does not even show up in my menu bar.

[Another view of my Spyder menu tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxpbh.png)

How do I get Spyder 3.0 to run my files again? Thank you, world.

Comment: Updates! So in Spyder I had a temp.py tab open that DID let me run files and what not, like it always did. So I thought I would just copy and paste my code into that tab and save it into the directory I want my .py to work on.

The moment I did that, I lost the ability to run the file. I try typing my arguments into the IPython console and it tells me that they're not defined.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but not identical in S3: F5 does nothing. But hitting the arrow icon does run my file (it is a .py file btw). Turns out this is a known problem on new Dell xps machines and if you hit ctrl-esc it gets things right and F5 starts working again. Look at the *second* (NOT THE ACCEPTED) answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88063/how-to-invert-fn-keys-on-dell-laptop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like that you have not saved your file as a python file. You must have "*file.py*". Not just "*file*".

Comment: you have correctly identified the problem! Spyder only lets users to run Python files, and for that files have to end up with the `.py` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem. Once I save my code turns white (I have a "skin" which is why its different) And it wouldn't let me run the file. I noticed that the saved file was in a different format which is probably be the cause. But I just did a simple factory reset and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

If (control + enter) or  (shift + enter) don't work in your spider then please try "F9" key. hope fully its works and you will be able to code line by line.

Comment: Please explain why `F9` is going to work if after all this time with,  nobody else has come up with that answer.  How is `F9` different from whatever else has been tried?